# Xcode debugger showing unexplainable info in debug area

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

While trying to debug my iPhone app in Xcode I encountered information in the debug area that I do not understand.

Here comes the code that I'm debugging. The breakpoint which suspended program execution and where the screenshot was taken is where is says "<<-- BREAKPOINT HERE":

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    CBDetailBackSegue *backSegue = [[CBDetailBackSegue alloc] init];
    NSInteger *posInArray = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2;
    backSegue.destinationViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:posInArray];
    backSegue.navigationController = self.navigationController;
    //backSegue.sourceViewController = self;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];  // <<-- BREAKPOINT HERE
    //[backSegue perform];
}
```

I want to inspect the contents of the variable `backSegue`, which is of type `CBDetailBackSegue*`. Telling from the code, I expect the instance to have the properties `sourceViewController`, `destinationViewController`, and `navigationController`.
But when viewing the instance's content in the debug area (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMQTC.png)), it appears to be a subtype of UIViewController and seems to have the properties of one of my UIViewController subclasses.

Does the debug area display wrong information or what's going on here?

[enlarge screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMQTC.png)
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you in Debug or Release 'build configuration' ?

Comment: I'm in debug (guess you mean in project's settings -> Build Settings)

Comment: Does CBDetailBackSeque have a custom `init` method?  Is it returning `self`, and are you sure you didn't assign some other item (other than the result of super init) to `self`?

Comment: no, I meant Edit Scheme > Info > 'build configuration'. Because I think I had strange behavior from LLDB when debugging on 'release'. Although I just tested it, and it seems to be OK. Nevermind :)

Comment: No, the CBDetailBackSegue does not have a custom `init` method.

Comment: @Vinzzz: There it's set to Debug as well.